# Controlling user images in FirebaseStorage

Tags: java, android, firebase, firebase-storage

I am making a social app on Android using Firebase. Each user can upload up to three images, which is stored using FirebaseStorage.

[Activity where users add photos](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gE286.png)

I am using the user's unique ID to name the photos. So for example a user's photos will be called: userid_1.jpg, userid_2.jpg, userid_3.jpg

I am using the first picture as the user's profile picture. This is all fine and well, but I want to allow the user to delete photos and add new ones.

So for example, the user has three photos and deletes the first one, so now photo2 moves to photo1's spot, and photo3 takes photo2's spot. So I can get this effect in the activity easily:

```
photo1ImageView.setImageDrawable(photo2ImageView.getDrawable());
photo2ImageView.setImageDrawable(photo3ImageView.getDrawable());
photo3ImageView.setImageResource(R.drawable.addphotoicon);
```

But now the problem is how to handle this in FirebaseStorage. So obviously I start off by deleting the picture.

```
FirebaseStorage.getInstance().getReference().child("images").child(userID + "_1.jpg").delete();
```

And then what I wanted to do was rename the remaining two pictures.

So after deleting photo1, userid_1.jpg falls away, userid_2.jpg becomes userid_1.jpg, userid_3.jpg becomes userid_2.jpg

But it is not possible to rename files in FirebaseStorage. So now when this activity loads the next time, it will put photo2 in the second ImageView and photo3 in the third ImageView, leaving the first ImageView blank. The profile picture (userid_1.jpg) will also be lost. This is not the behaviour that I want.

Another way I thought of is: whenever a photo is deleted, I would delete all the user's photos, and re-upload the remaining ones with the correct names, but this is very inefficient and unnecessary usage on Firebase.

I am just wondering if anyone can think of an efficient way to do this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Cloud Storage is not very good at maintaining the sequence of objects uploaded to it.  Not even most normal computer filesystems are good for this.

I suggest abandoning the idea that Storage will maintain any sort of order or sequence, and move that logic entirely into a database or other data storage that does give you the ability to easily order items in it.  The names of the files uploaded to storage can just be random - they don't need any meaning.  You just need to store their paths in the related records in the database, and keep the two in sync.

Answer (score 0):

You can apply a little trick here.
Store your user photo reference into you database as an object array. Create a model class for your photo. which can be look like this:

```
class UserPhoto {
    var photoRef: String? = null //Reference of your photo in Cloud Storage
    var downloadUrl: String? = null //This is optional, but very handy.
    var timestamp: Long? = null // In milseconds
    var order: Int = -1
}
```

Here you can see "timestamp" and "order" is the key to find if the photo is the latest one or not. Just store this data as an array in User document. Each photo will have this data. Then, you can put your logic into you app/server according to this data model for each user photo.